# Integral involving $\theta_3(z,q)$ with respect to $z$

Tags: integration, theta-functions

I'm studying Dirichlet kernels and their related identities; I've stumbled upon a "weighted Dirichlet kernel" so to speak. I'd like to find a closed form for the summation.

To do so, I'm required to integrate something along the lines of
\begin{align}
\int dz e^{-\alpha z^2-\beta z} \theta_3(z,q)
\end{align}
(i.e. the indefinite integral)

Usage of special functions is fine (I've already decided to use the elliptic functions so it can't get much worse).

I found a few identities involving integration with respect to $q$, but nothing about integration with respect to $z$. I already know the series representation (this is precisely the representation I'm interested in). I'm wondering if some closed form of the above exists, and what the existing literature, or the people on mathSE can tell me about it. I myself have no idea where to start, and I would certainly be interested in solving the integral in some sort of closed form.

Comment: Special functions : complicated functions with a lot of non-trivial interesting properties. They aren't closed under integration, ie. there are good chances we can't say anything about your primitive of a gaussian times a theta function, except for the asymptotic on a few directions. In those cases you need to explain the context, why you'd need such a thing.

Comment: @reuns Many thanks for your comment. I am studying weighted "Dirichlet-like" kernels, so my "simple case" is: $\sum_{-n}^n exp(-kx)/(k+a)$. This can be solved using Lerch transcendents. My more complicated case will have $\exp(-k^2 t - k x)$ in the numerator ($x,t$ variables in the plane). I'm trying to find an identity that is an extended idea of the Lerch transcendent identity but with the square in the exponent. Roughly my idea was to construct this summation using integrations of the Jacobi theta function times some appropriate power of the nome. Surely this should be possible? ...

Comment: So the function you want is $\nu(a,b,t) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-t n^2 + an}}{n+b}$,
$e^{-tN^2+aN}\nu(a-2Nt,N+b)=\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{e^{-tn^2 + an}}{n+b}$

and $\frac{d}{da}e^{ab}\nu(a,b,t)=e^{ab}\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-tn^2 + an}=e^{ab}\vartheta(t,a)$ is the incomplete theta function, which is the inverse Mellin transform (in $t$) of $\Gamma(s)Li_{2s}(e^a)$. The incomplete theta function isn't really a special function : it lacks most of the interesting properties of the complete one.

Comment: @reuns This is not related to the same question but interesting nonetheless. What is known about "higher order" and complex polynomials in the exponent? So for example $\exp(iAn^3-iBn^2+iCn)$ instead of the above?